# Optimize SQL-Query several JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have an SQL query with a nested join:

```
SELECT rh.host, rh.report, COUNT(results.id), COUNT(results_2.id), COUNT(results_3.id), COUNT(results_4.id)
FROM report_hosts rh
INNER JOIN report_results rr ON rh.report = rr.report
LEFT OUTER JOIN results ON rr.result = results.id AND results.type =  'Hole' AND results.host = rh.host
LEFT OUTER JOIN results results_2 ON rr.result = results_2.id AND results_2.type =  'Warning' AND results_2.host = rh.host
LEFT OUTER JOIN results results_3 ON rr.result = results_3.id AND results_3.type =  'Note' AND results_3.host = rh.host
LEFT OUTER JOIN results results_4 ON rr.result = results_4.id AND results_4.type =  'Log' AND results_4.host = rh.host
GROUP BY rh.host
```

The query as-is takes about 5sec with 99.7% *copying to temp table*. An `EXPLAIN` of the full query shows as:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rr        | ALL    | report        | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 3139 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rh        | ref    | report        | report  | 5       | openvas.rr.report |  167 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | results   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type  | PRIMARY | 4       | openvas.rr.result |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | results_2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type  | PRIMARY | 4       | openvas.rr.result |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | results_3 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type  | PRIMARY | 4       | openvas.rr.result |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | results_4 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type  | PRIMARY | 4       | openvas.rr.result |    1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

When I remove the `LEFT JOIN`s, the query executes in about 1s, each `LEFT JOIN` adds about one additional second execution time.

**My question:**
Can anyone explain, why the *copy to temp table* task of one join takes longer if there are more `LEFT JOIN`s? Is MySQL copying the temp table several times for each JOIN?

How can I avoid this? Am I missing an index?

**What I intend to accomplish:**
I have a table with scanning results of several hosts. Each result is classified in types ( "Hole", "Warning", "Note" or "Log"). I want to select each host and the corresponding amount of Holes, Warnings, Notes and Logs. As a "restriction" I have the fact, that not each host has each type of results.

Comment: If results1 and results2 both have 10 matching records, you now have 100 records.  And each left join multiplies that further.  This is not the query you are looking for.  [I'd post more, but I'm on a phone]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're joining a single table several times, which effectively is like joining multiple tables. You should be able to handle that with some case statements and a where clause instead. (In fact you may not need the where clause.)

```
SELECT rh.host, rh.report, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN results.type = 'Hole' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Holes, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN results.type = 'Warning' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Warnings,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN results.type = 'Note' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Notes, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN results.type = 'Log' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Logs
FROM 
 report_hosts rh
INNER JOIN 
 report_results rr 
ON 
 rh.report = rr.report
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 results 
ON 
 rr.result = results.id 
 AND results.host = rh.host
WHERE
 results.type = 'Hole' 
 OR results.type = 'Warning' 
 OR results.type = 'Note' 
 OR results.type = 'Log'
GROUP BY rh.host, rh.report
```

Case statements, IME, are not the greatest performers, but your data bloat from the many joins may offset that and give this better performance.

Comment: Great idea to avoid the multiple-joins! The query takes only 1sec. But, one weird thing: If I omit the `WHERE` clause, the execution takes more than 10sec. The `results` table has 6000 rows, but only 600 rows do *not* match the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If `results.type` is an index they it's counting they indexed values when using `WHERE` when not using `WHERE` it's doing a full table scan.

Comment: So the reason is, that only a `WHERE` clause can "request" an index, but not an aggregate function?

Answer (score 1):

Using a lot of data (in your case an extra `left join`) will mean storing it in memory.

If you deplete the buffers your query will need to be stored to a temporary result table on drive.

Try using the same number of `left join`s but limiting the number of rows with a `limit`. It should confirm that the problem lies in the buffers (meaning it will run faster).

Comment: I recognized, the problem are the `LEFT JOIN`s. With `INNER JOIN`s, it's much faster, but I guess my query is not doable with inner joins, is it?

Comment: Inner join Mostly handle less data, that is why it is faster in direct comparison.

Comment: *doable* depends on your needs. `Left joins` grab all the values in the left-side table and any available values for the right-side table (nulls otherwise). `Inner joins` only grab the values on the left-side that have correspondents on the right-side. Which as YvesR said means less values. I have no idea what your tables are used for or what the data in them is so i can't tell you if selecting more ore less data will be ok.

Comment: I have added my aim I want to accomplish with the query. Maybe SQL is not the best way to accomplish this and I should do the "heavy" part in my programming language.

Comment: Doing large dataset manipulations in a programming language has a few downsides such as: 1) if the language is not C it most likely will not have top performance, 2) if you are not a seasoned programmer with an eye for sorting/filtering algorithms you'll end up adding to the slowdown.

Comment: If the query @Ilion proposed works and yield the results you'd expect I'd recommend it.